# Installing MS Office 2013 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, wine, microsoft-office

I am trying to install Microsoft Office 2013 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (32-bit). I have downloaded an `iso` file of said product and installed `wine1.4-i386` using the `apt-get` command on the terminal.

The question is I don't know the steps how to install it. I can't get much tutorials on Internet how MSOffice2013 can be installed on Ubuntu.

If any versions of `wine` isn't an option, what other options can be used to run Microsoft Office 2013?

Comment: I don't think you can install office 2013 using wine as well as it's not supported yet.

Comment: Even the 32-bit wine is installed? Is there another to install MSOffice 2013?

Comment: That's true.  It will not run. You can try Office 2010.  See [Here](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=17336).

Comment: Only Office 2010 32-bit, though (as I say below)... and I suggest he tries AbiWord for his doc processor, it's compatible with DocX, and arguable faster and nicer than word... no need for Wine, as well! :)

Comment: Try older versions of Microsoft Office.  The best one I use office 2007, although 2010 also works to some extent.  the only way I can see of getting office 2013 to work is on a Windows virtual machine

Comment: [this Softpedia page](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Microsoft-Office-2013-Installation-Works-with-Wine-1-7-10-413664.shtml) says wine 1.7.10 should work with msoffice2013. Trying to confirm that, no success.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to [Wine HQ](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26323), Microsoft Office 2013, can't be installed.

I you would suggest that you look at Libreoffice, or if insist on MS office, you can try Office 365.

Comment: Even though I've installed the 32-bit support of `wine`?

Comment: That's true. It will not run. You can try Office 2010. See [Here](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=17336).

Comment: Is there any other option to run Microsoft Office 2013?

Comment: Load windows under a VM, such as [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or [VMware](http://www.vmware.com/), and install office that way.  VirtualBox is a free application, where as VMware is not.

Comment: Can be an option, but that will use up memory. I'm only using a netbook. I don't think virtual approach could be an option.

Comment: As I stated before, you can try office 2010.  Any specific reason you want to use 2013? if you don't mind me asking.

Comment: I've preferred using MS2013 some of the features are not equal with other open source document programs (OpenOffice, LibreOffice, etc).

Comment: @Mitch It's worth noting if he tries that, that only the 32-bit 2010 installer works, NOT the 64-bit version for some reason (source: WINE HQ http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=31 )

Comment: JUST install Wine and winbind, afterthat install Office 2013 32 bit from ISO> exe file
https://flic.kr/p/2oPnU2n

Answer (score 25):

I suggest you use [AbiWord](http://www.abisource.com/) instead.  It's compatible with DocX and you has a number of advantages over word (no, I'm not joking, really)... there's a good reason why it's referred to affectionately as ["the underappreciated word processor"](http://www.linuxplanet.com/linuxplanet/reviews/7076/1/) by some.

As for the rest of Office, I suggest you do one of four things:

1. If you must have Office 2013, it [doesn't current work](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26323) w/ Wine... so use VMWare, etc. 
   **ADVANTAGES:** the
   software you want! 
   **DISADVANTAGES:** in separate
   environment)
2. [Install Office 2010 instead on Wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=17336). **IMPORTANT!!** (I don't recall seeing anyone else put this... *ONLY the 32-bit version works*.  The [64-bit won't install](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=18487) (just like 2013).

   **ADVANTAGES:** faster access, probably more responsive, easier
   file access! 
   **DISADVANTAGES:** you may miss some of 2013's
   features if you're a power user or find it less visually appealing,
   depending on your preferences.)
3. Get an Office 365
   subscription.  Test if it the desktop versions will install in Wine (and add your results [here](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=31), please).
   Even if they won't [you can still use the in-browser version](http://www.pcpro.co.uk/blogs/2012/03/28/is-office-365-the-best-thing-thats-ever-happened-to-linux/) when
   your internet connected (which I assume is most of the time)

   **ADVANTAGES:** fast, your data auto-saves and is accessible
   anywhere from the cloud in-browser! 
   **DISADVANTAGES:** major step
   down in functionalility.)
4. Switch to an open source or
   third party alternative, e.g. [Libre Office](http://www.libreoffice.org/) (widely distributed w/
   Linux) or [Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/) (in the cloud) 
   **ADVANTAGES:** Probably free!
   Inherent advantages if you pick a cloud app.  Personal satisfaction
   if you support open source! 
   **DISADVANTAGES:** Probably lacks
   compatibility w/ at least some Office features.

Hope that helps!

P.S. I'm not sure why some downvoted you -- this seems a valid question.  True, you might not have provided all the possible info (e.g. why you're not considering Office 2010 or an alternative like Libre Office), but you asked a relatively clear question, which is perfectly reasonable from a beginner-to-mid-range user.  Let's be respectful... I digress.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed information. I appreciated it. I will try this until MS Office 2013 to be able to run on ubuntu without making a virtual for its environment

Comment: No problem, let me know how it goes! :)

Comment: Worth noting for anyone who finds this - Office 365 is NOT a different desktop software product from Office 2013. It is the same binaries and software. The licensing is different, but what is installed is the exact same product as a single-license retail copy of Office 2013.

Answer (score 8):

You can also try:

1. [WinConn](http://stanev.org/winconn/). This is a remote app manager that uses FreeRDP, a free implementation of the RDP protocol. It allows you to run office 2013 in a virtual machine(Make sure you use Windows 7 Ultimate edition!), but it looks like you're just running a local application in a seperate window.
2. Office 2010 with [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/). This is software based on Wine.
3. [Office 365 in your browser](https://office.live.com/start/Word.aspx).
4. Skydrive in your browser. You can then create a Word document/PowerPoint presentation/Excel document/OneNote note free of charge. Keep in mind though you just got a limited set of features(It's actually a stripped down version of a paid Office 365 account)
5. Google docs
6. [Kingsoft office for linux](http://wps-community.org/download.html). Although it's still in alpha stage, Kingsoft office for Windows has build up a reputation for being a worthy alternative to Microsoft Office.

Comment: Kingsoft office is really great. I use it all the time. What I love is that Linux users get loads of Pro features by default, like the Ribbon. One thing to note is that when installing on a 64-bit system you MUST install `ia32-libs` **first**! Otherwise, nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

Codeweavers Crossover 16.0 now has support for Office 2013 (3/5 star rating of this post). You have to use the iso installer, not the online downloader.

You can check it out here: https://www.codeweavers.com/compatibility/crossover/microsoft-office-2013

Answer (score 0):

[PlayOnLinux beta installer script](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-2665-Microsoft_Office_2013.html) supports Office 2013. It uses Wine 1.8-staging. PlayOnLinux is a Wine GUI that allows you to install multiple Windows programs on Linux operating systems.

WORKS FOR ANY VERSION OF UBUNTU

It comes with the adequate configuration for multiple applications and games, you have to have only the installer and then follow the program instructions.

[image]

For installing it run the following commands:

To add the repository that contains the program:

```
wget https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key
sudo apt-key add Release.key
sudo apt-add-repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/'
sudo apt-get update
```

And to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

Then install Microsoft Office Pack 2013, also works for 2010 and multiple games:
[image]