# Black Screen Issue in Office 2013 using Wine 2.0

Tags: wine, winetricks, microsoft-office

I have successfully installed Office 2013 with wine version 2.0 but once any of the applications (Word, PowerPoint, etc.) launches it give a black window and a smaller white windows (I guess it is the activation window), then after a while it crashes. Similar to the problem described in [AppDB Word 2013](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=33708) Would this be a dependency issue? Is there anything I have to install with winetricks? I've only installed dotnet45.

Wine 2.0 is suppose to support MS Office 2013 as it is highlighted in https://www.winehq.org/announce/2.0.

Backtrace.txt below

```
Unhandled exception: 0xe0000002 in 32-bit code (0x7b43cd8c).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
 EIP:7b43cd8c ESP:00337ad4 EBP:00337b58 EFLAGS:00200216(   - --  I   -A-P- )
 EAX:7b429645 EBX:7b63c000 ECX:7b43ccf0 EDX:00000000
 ESI:00000000 EDI:00337c7c
Stack dump:
0x00337ad4:  00000001 ffffffc0 00337c90 00338178
0x00337ae4:  f753b1e5 0033816c e0000002 00000000
0x00337af4:  00000000 7b43cd8c 00000000 00338100
0x00337b04:  00000000 00000000 f7420a57 f7590c20
0x00337b14:  00000000 00000000 ffffffc0 00000002
0x00337b24:  00337b78 7bcb25e3 ffffff63 7bcb25e2
Backtrace:
=>0 0x7b43cd8c in kernel32 (+0x2cd8c) (0x00337b58)
  1 0x024e5d5b in mso (+0x1055d5a) (0x00337d18)
  2 0x7bc6dc23 in ntdll (+0x5dc22) (0x00337dd8)
  3 0x7bc6e194 NtOpenKeyEx+0x23() in ntdll (0x00337df8)
  4 0x7eb01235 RegOpenKeyExW+0x154() in advapi32 (0x00337e78)
  5 0x014927c0 in mso (+0x27bf) (0x00337e98)
  6 0x0149279b in mso (+0x279a) (0x00337eb0)
  7 0x01497ef4 in mso (+0x7ef3) (0x0033813c)
  8 0x0149780b in mso (+0x780a) (0x00338188)
  9 0x01497744 in mso (+0x7743) (0x003381d0)
  10 0x014976c1 in mso (+0x76c0) (0x003381e4)
  11 0x014da7db in mso (+0x4a7da) (0x00338268)
  12 0x014eba03 in mso (+0x5ba02) (0x0033829c)
  13 0x014eb9b8 in mso (+0x5b9b7) (0x003384fc)
  14 0x10015e28 in wwlib (+0x15e27) (0x0033aa68)
  15 0x10015928 in wwlib (+0x15927) (0x0033aaa8)
  16 0x7e7f076a WINPROC_wrapper+0x19() in user32 (0x0033aad8)
  17 0x7e7f0d9a in user32 (+0x90d99) (0x0033ab28)
  18 0x7e7f34e3 CallWindowProcW+0x62() in user32 (0x0033ab88)
  19 0x7c2eaf69 DefSubclassProc+0x118() in comctl32 (0x0033abe8)
  20 0x0150c907 in mso (+0x7c906) (0x0033ac3c)
  21 0x0150c39f in mso (+0x7c39e) (0x0033ac68)
  22 0x7c2eaec4 DefSubclassProc+0x73() in comctl32 (0x0033acb8)
  23 0x7c2eb017 in comctl32 (+0x1b016) (0x0033ad08)
  24 0x7e7f076a WINPROC_wrapper+0x19() in user32 (0x0033ad48)
  25 0x7e7f0d9a in user32 (+0x90d99) (0x0033ad98)
  26 0x7e7f3235 in user32 (+0x93234) (0x0033ade8)
  27 0x7e7b51fe in user32 (+0x551fd) (0x0033ae58)
  28 0x7e7bbfc4 in user32 (+0x5bfc3) (0x0033aeb8)
  29 0x7e7bc260 SendMessageW+0x5f() in user32 (0x0033af08)
  30 0x7e7978ef in user32 (+0x378ee) (0x0033b018)
  31 0x7e797b1e in user32 (+0x37b1d) (0x0033b0d8)
  32 0x7e797c4c SetForegroundWindow+0x5b() in user32 (0x0033b108)
  33 0x7dfad7d8 in winex11 (+0xd7d7) (0x0033b198)
  34 0x7dfb08a0 in winex11 (+0x1089f) (0x0033b228)
  35 0x7dfadf73 in winex11 (+0xdf72) (0x0033b258)
  36 0x7dfaf835 in winex11 (+0xf834) (0x0033b3a8)
  37 0x7dfb0a83 in winex11 (+0x10a82) (0x0033b3d8)
  38 0x7e7f104e in user32 (+0x9104d) (0x0033b438)
  39 0x7e7b5334 in user32 (+0x55333) (0x0033b508)
  40 0x7e7b7751 MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0xd0() in user32 (0x0033b658)
  41 0x7e7b77f8 MsgWaitForMultipleObjects+0x37() in user32 (0x0033b698)
  42 0x7c78f627 in urlmon (+0xf626) (0x0033b768)
  43 0x7c790136 in urlmon (+0x10135) (0x0033b7b8)
  44 0x7c7a7c1d in urlmon (+0x27c1c) (0x0033b7f8)
  45 0x7462925c in mshtml (+0xa925b) (0x0033b868)
  46 0x7465a7fc in mshtml (+0xda7fb) (0x0033b8c8)
  47 0x7465aaa4 in mshtml (+0xdaaa3) (0x0033b948)
  48 0x74623069 in mshtml (+0xa3068) (0x0033b9a8)
  49 0x74622d7f in mshtml (+0xa2d7e) (0x0033b9c8)
  50 0x0ab3e0a1 in xul (+0x9fe0a0) (0x0033ba58)
  51 0x746235fa in mshtml (+0xa35f9) (0x0033baa8)
  52 0x0ac12592 in xul (+0xad2591) (0x0033bb56)
0x7b43cd8c: addl    $12,%esp
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (231 modules)
PE    400000-  5d7000   Deferred        winword
PE    6f0000- 148f000   Deferred        oart
PE   1490000- 2cbf000   Export          mso
PE   70c0000- 70f1000   Deferred        ieawsdc
PE   72e0000- 73f6000   Deferred        msptls
PE   a140000- dad7000   Export          xul
PE  10000000-11490000   Export          wwlib
PE  661c0000-662a4000   Deferred        mozglue
PE  6b840000-6ba56000   Deferred        nss3
PE  6be90000-6bebd000   Deferred        osppc
PE  70a80000-70b5d000   Deferred        lgpllibs
ELF 72ab3000-72b5c000   Deferred        jscript<elf>
  \-PE  72ac0000-72b5c000   \               jscript
ELF 72b5c000-72c47000   Deferred        comdlg32<elf>
  \-PE  72b60000-72c47000   \               comdlg32
ELF 72c47000-72d00000   Deferred        winmm<elf>
  \-PE  72c50000-72d00000   \               winmm
ELF 74566000-74700000   Dwarf           mshtml<elf>
  \-PE  74580000-74700000   \               mshtml
ELF 74812000-74828000   Deferred        shcore<elf>
  \-PE  74820000-74828000   \               shcore
ELF 74828000-748f8000   Deferred        crypt32<elf>
  \-PE  74830000-748f8000   \               crypt32
ELF 74d07000-74d76000   Deferred        setupapi<elf>
  \-PE  74d10000-74d76000   \               setupapi
ELF 74d76000-74e00000   Deferred        ieframe<elf>
  \-PE  74d80000-74e00000   \               ieframe
ELF 74f0a000-74f41000   Deferred        wintrust<elf>
  \-PE  74f10000-74f41000   \               wintrust
ELF 74f41000-74f59000   Deferred        userenv<elf>
  \-PE  74f50000-74f59000   \               userenv
ELF 74f59000-74f75000   Deferred        rasapi32<elf>
  \-PE  74f60000-74f75000   \               rasapi32
ELF 74f75000-74fb0000   Deferred        webservices<elf>
  \-PE  74f80000-74fb0000   \               webservices
ELF 751e5000-75200000   Deferred        wsock32<elf>
  \-PE  751f0000-75200000   \               wsock32
ELF 7572b000-7576d000   Deferred        rsaenh<elf>
  \-PE  75730000-7576d000   \               rsaenh
ELF 76e09000-76e3f000   Deferred        msctf<elf>
  \-PE  76e10000-76e3f000   \               msctf
ELF 76e3f000-76e7b000   Deferred        winhttp<elf>
  \-PE  76e50000-76e7b000   \               winhttp
ELF 77f0b000-77f28000   Deferred        jsproxy<elf>
  \-PE  77f10000-77f28000   \               jsproxy
ELF 77f28000-77f3c000   Deferred        normaliz<elf>
  \-PE  77f30000-77f3c000   \               normaliz
ELF 77f3c000-77f52000   Deferred        libgpg-error.so.0
ELF 77f52000-77fc7000   Deferred        libpcre.so.3
ELF 77fc7000-78076000   Deferred        libgcrypt.so.20
ELF 78076000-7809c000   Deferred        liblzma.so.5
ELF 7809c000-780c2000   Deferred        libselinux.so.1
ELF 780c2000-78150000   Deferred        libsystemd.so.0
ELF 78150000-781aa000   Deferred        libdbus-1.so.3
ELF 781aa000-781b7000   Deferred        libkrb5support.so.0
ELF 781b7000-781e8000   Deferred        libk5crypto.so.3
ELF 781e8000-782be000   Deferred        libkrb5.so.3
ELF 782be000-782d2000   Deferred        libavahi-client.so.3
ELF 782d2000-78324000   Deferred        libgssapi_krb5.so.2
ELF 78324000-783ab000   Deferred        libcups.so.2
ELF 783ab000-783ce000   Deferred        xmllite<elf>
  \-PE  783b0000-783ce000   \               xmllite
ELF 783ce000-7840d000   Deferred        winspool<elf>
  \-PE  783e0000-7840d000   \               winspool
ELF 78429000-7843f000   Deferred        dwmapi<elf>
  \-PE  78430000-7843f000   \               dwmapi
ELF 7843f000-78500000   Deferred        msvcrt<elf>
  \-PE  78460000-78500000   \               msvcrt
ELF 78606000-78614000   Deferred        libavahi-common.so.3
ELF 78614000-78659000   Deferred        usp10<elf>
  \-PE  78620000-78659000   \               usp10
ELF 78659000-786d6000   Deferred        riched20<elf>
  \-PE  78660000-786d6000   \               riched20
ELF 786d6000-78762000   Deferred        libgmp.so.10
ELF 78762000-7879e000   Deferred        libnettle.so.6
ELF 7879e000-788f6000   Deferred        libgnutls.so.30
ELF 7a800000-7a935000   Deferred        opengl32<elf>
  \-PE  7a820000-7a935000   \               opengl32
ELF 7a936000-7a96b000   Deferred        libhogweed.so.4
ELF 7a96b000-7a99f000   Deferred        libidn.so.11
ELF 7a99f000-7aa00000   Deferred        libp11-kit.so.0
ELF 7ab07000-7ab20000   Deferred        libresolv.so.2
ELF 7ab20000-7ab40000   Deferred        dnsapi<elf>
  \-PE  7ab30000-7ab40000   \               dnsapi
ELF 7ab40000-7ab6a000   Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
  \-PE  7ab50000-7ab6a000   \               iphlpapi
ELF 7ab6a000-7ab9a000   Deferred        netapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7ab70000-7ab9a000   \               netapi32
ELF 7ab9a000-7ac00000   Deferred        dbghelp<elf>
  \-PE  7aba0000-7ac00000   \               dbghelp
ELF 7af00000-7af1d000   Deferred        netprofm<elf>
  \-PE  7af10000-7af1d000   \               netprofm
ELF 7af1d000-7af4f000   Deferred        secur32<elf>
  \-PE  7af20000-7af4f000   \               secur32
ELF 7b400000-7b7e4000   Dwarf           kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b410000-7b7e4000   \               kernel32
ELF 7b7ec000-7b84f000   Deferred        dwrite<elf>
  \-PE  7b7f0000-7b84f000   \               dwrite
ELF 7bc00000-7bcfe000   Dwarf           ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc10000-7bcfe000   \               ntdll
ELF 7bd07000-7bd3d000   Deferred        mscoree<elf>
  \-PE  7bd10000-7bd3d000   \               mscoree
ELF 7bd3d000-7be00000   Deferred        windowscodecs<elf>
  \-PE  7bd50000-7be00000   \               windowscodecs
ELF 7c000000-7c004000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF 7c004000-7c019000   Deferred        libtasn1.so.6
ELF 7c019000-7c02d000   Deferred        psapi<elf>
  \-PE  7c020000-7c02d000   \               psapi
ELF 7c222000-7c237000   Deferred        rasdlg<elf>
  \-PE  7c230000-7c237000   \               rasdlg
ELF 7c237000-7c251000   Deferred        cryptnet<elf>
  \-PE  7c240000-7c251000   \               cryptnet
ELF 7c251000-7c266000   Deferred        schannel<elf>
  \-PE  7c260000-7c266000   \               schannel
ELF 7c292000-7c2ca000   Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
  \-PE  7c2a0000-7c2ca000   \               uxtheme
ELF 7c2ca000-7c3c6000   Dwarf           comctl32<elf>
  \-PE  7c2d0000-7c3c6000   \               comctl32
ELF 7c3c6000-7c400000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE  7c3d0000-7c400000   \               ws2_32
ELF 7c40a000-7c411000   Deferred        libnss_dns.so.2
ELF 7c419000-7c439000   Deferred        cabinet<elf>
  \-PE  7c420000-7c439000   \               cabinet
ELF 7c439000-7c4b1000   Deferred        wininet<elf>
  \-PE  7c440000-7c4b1000   \               wininet
ELF 7c4b1000-7c770000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7c4c0000-7c770000   \               shell32
ELF 7c770000-7c80d000   Dwarf           urlmon<elf>
  \-PE  7c780000-7c80d000   \               urlmon
ELF 7c80d000-7c8ff000   Deferred        msi<elf>
  \-PE  7c820000-7c8ff000   \               msi
ELF 7cb16000-7cb3e000   Deferred        mpr<elf>
  \-PE  7cb20000-7cb3e000   \               mpr
ELF 7cc4d000-7cc56000   Deferred        libffi.so.6
ELF 7cc56000-7cc5b000   Deferred        libkeyutils.so.1
ELF 7cc5b000-7cc60000   Deferred        libcom_err.so.2
ELF 7cff6000-7d002000   Deferred        libpciaccess.so.0
ELF 7d002000-7d010000   Deferred        libdrm_radeon.so.1
ELF 7d010000-7d01a000   Deferred        libdrm_nouveau.so.2
ELF 7d01a000-7d03f000   Deferred        libdrm_intel.so.1
ELF 7d03f000-7d6f9000   Deferred        i965_dri.so
ELF 7d6f9000-7d702000   Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF 7d702000-7d723000   Deferred        libudev.so.1
ELF 7d723000-7d735000   Deferred        libdrm.so.2
ELF 7d735000-7d73b000   Deferred        libxcb-dri2.so.0
ELF 7d73b000-7d756000   Deferred        libxcb-glx.so.0
ELF 7d756000-7d759000   Deferred        libx11-xcb.so.1
ELF 7d759000-7d75d000   Deferred        libxdamage.so.1
ELF 7d75d000-7d779000   Deferred        libglapi.so.0
ELF 7d779000-7d7e8000   Deferred        libgl.so.1
ELF 7d80b000-7d823000   Deferred        wtsapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7d810000-7d823000   \               wtsapi32
ELF 7d99a000-7d9d1000   Deferred        libtxc_dxtn_s2tc.so.0
ELF 7d9d1000-7d9d4000   Deferred        libxshmfence.so.1
ELF 7d9d4000-7d9dc000   Deferred        libxcb-sync.so.1
ELF 7d9dc000-7d9e0000   Deferred        libxcb-present.so.0
ELF 7d9e0000-7d9f4000   Deferred        msimg32<elf>
  \-PE  7d9f0000-7d9f4000   \               msimg32
ELF 7d9f4000-7d9fb000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF 7d9fb000-7da06000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7da06000-7da0a000   Deferred        libxcb-dri3.so.0
ELF 7da0a000-7da27000   Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1
ELF 7dc03000-7dc2d000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7dc2d000-7dc76000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7dc76000-7dd26000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7dd26000-7de71000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 7deb7000-7dee2000   Deferred        libpng12.so.0
ELF 7dee2000-7defd000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7defd000-7df10000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF 7df10000-7df14000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7df14000-7df21000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7df21000-7df2d000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 7df2d000-7df53000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 7df53000-7df68000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 7df8b000-7e019000   Dwarf           winex11<elf>
  \-PE  7dfa0000-7e019000   \               winex11
ELF 7e019000-7e03d000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE  7e020000-7e03d000   \               imm32
ELF 7e03d000-7e0b1000   Deferred        d3dcompiler_43<elf>
  \-PE  7e050000-7e0b1000   \               d3dcompiler_43
ELF 7e0b1000-7e0f0000   Deferred        d3d10<elf>
  \-PE  7e0c0000-7e0f0000   \               d3d10
ELF 7e0f0000-7e228000   Deferred        wined3d<elf>
  \-PE  7e100000-7e228000   \               wined3d
ELF 7e228000-7e252000   Deferred        dxgi<elf>
  \-PE  7e230000-7e252000   \               dxgi
ELF 7e252000-7e2c2000   Deferred        d3d11<elf>
  \-PE  7e260000-7e2c2000   \               d3d11
ELF 7e2c2000-7e2d8000   Deferred        d3d10core<elf>
  \-PE  7e2d0000-7e2d8000   \               d3d10core
ELF 7e2d8000-7e2ee000   Deferred        d3d10_1<elf>
  \-PE  7e2e0000-7e2ee000   \               d3d10_1
ELF 7e2ee000-7e33f000   Deferred        d2d1<elf>
  \-PE  7e2f0000-7e33f000   \               d2d1
ELF 7e33f000-7e458000   Deferred        msvcp100<elf>
  \-PE  7e380000-7e458000   \               msvcp100
ELF 7e458000-7e58b000   Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
  \-PE  7e470000-7e58b000   \               oleaut32
ELF 7e58b000-7e60b000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7e5a0000-7e60b000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7e60b000-7e744000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  7e620000-7e744000   \               ole32
ELF 7e744000-7e89a000   Dwarf           user32<elf>
  \-PE  7e760000-7e89a000   \               user32
ELF 7e89a000-7e912000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e8b0000-7e912000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7e912000-7e9a1000   Deferred        gdiplus<elf>
  \-PE  7e920000-7e9a1000   \               gdiplus
ELF 7e9a1000-7ead1000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e9b0000-7ead1000   \               gdi32
ELF 7ead1000-7eb48000   Dwarf           advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7eae0000-7eb48000   \               advapi32
ELF 7eb48000-7ec1d000   Deferred        msvcr100<elf>
  \-PE  7eb60000-7ec1d000   \               msvcr100
ELF 7ec1d000-7ec30000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7ec30000-7ec3d000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 7ec3d000-7ec58000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7ef88000-7efdd000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7efdf000-7efe6000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7efe6000-7f000000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  7eff0000-7f000000   \               version
ELF f73d1000-f73d8000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF f73d9000-f73de000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF f73de000-f7594000   Deferred        libc.so.6
ELF f7595000-f75b2000   Deferred        libpthread.so.0
ELF f75b2000-f75b6000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF f75b6000-f75c0000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF f75d0000-f75d4000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF f75d5000-f77a6000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f77a8000-f77cd000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF f77cf000-f77d0000   Deferred        [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
00000008 reg.exe
    [C:\windows\system32\reg.exe delete HKLM\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727\SBSDisabled]
    00000009    0
0000000e services.exe
    [C:\windows\system32\services.exe]
    00000132    0
    00000131    0
    0000012b    0
    0000011b    0
    0000008d    0
    00000021    0
    00000016    0
    00000012    0
    0000000f    0
00000010 explorer.exe
    [C:\windows\system32\explorer.exe /desktop]
    00000028    0
    00000027    0
    00000026    0
    00000025    0
    00000011    0
00000014 winedevice.exe
    [C:\windows\system32\winedevice.exe]
    00000020    0
    0000001b    0
    0000001a    0
    00000015    0
0000001e plugplay.exe
    [C:\windows\system32\plugplay.exe]
    00000024    0
    00000023    0
    0000001f    0
0000008b svchost.exe
    [C:\windows\system32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs]
    00000090    0
    0000008f    0
    0000008c    0
00000119 OSPPSVC.EXE
    ["C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OfficeSoftwareProtectionPlatform\OSPPSVC.EXE"]
    000001e4    0
    000001de    0
    000001da    0
    000001d6    0
    000001d8    0
    000001d5    0
    000001d7    0
    000001cc    0
    000001cd    0
    000001ce    0
    000001c6    0
    000001c3    0
    000001c8    0
    000001bf    0
    000001c2    0
    000001c1    0
    000001be    0
    000001bc    0
    000001bb    0
    000001b3    0
    000001b5    0
    000001b0    0
    000001ac    0
    000001af    0
    000001b1    0
    00000121    0
    0000010e    0
    00000120    0
    0000010a    0
    0000010d    0
    0000010c    0
    0000011a    0
00000129 svchost.exe
    [C:\windows\system32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs]
    00000143    0
    0000013d    0
    00000128    0
    0000012e    0
    0000012d    0
    0000012a    0
0000012f rpcss.exe
    [C:\windows\system32\rpcss.exe]
    000001e2    0
    000001e1    0
    00000138    0
    00000124    0
    00000127    0
    00000135    0
    00000134    0
    00000133    0
    00000130    0
0000018c (D) C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\WINWORD.EXE
    ["C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\WINWORD.EXE"]
    00000079    0
    00000074    0
    00000069    0
    00000068    0
    00000063    0
    00000064    0
    00000066    0
    00000061    0
    00000065    0
    00000043    0
    00000038    0
    0000005c    0
    00000058    0
    00000039    0
    0000004a    0
    0000002e    0
    00000019    0
    0000000a    0
    000001ed    0
    000001ee    0
    000001f0    0
    000001eb    0
    000001ef    0
    000001ff    0
    000001fc    0
    000001f7   -1
    000001f4    0
    000001f3    0
    000001f2    0
    00000200    0
    00000201    0
    00000203    0
    00000202   -1
    000001fd   -1
    000001fe    0
    000001f8    0
    000001f9    0
    000001fb    0
    000001fa    0
    000001f5    0
    000001f6    0
    000001ec    0
    000001e7    0
    000001e8    0
    000001ea    0
    000001e3    0
    000001e9    0
    000001a5    0
    000001a1    0
    00000190    1
    000001a3    0
    0000019f    0 <==
0000005d explorer.exe
    [C:\windows\system32\explorer.exe /desktop]
    00000086    0
    00000071    0
    00000082    0
    00000088    0
    00000087    0
System information:
    Wine build: wine-2.0 (Staging)
    Platform: i386
    Version: Windows 7
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 4.4.0-51-generic
```

Comment: Please give more detail as to your question. We're a "solve-a-specific-problem" site, not a "tell-us-what-you-want-and-we'll-do-it" site.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to as Libre Office covers all the bases for me. A quick check of the [Wine HQ AppDB](https://www.winehq.org/search?q=Office+2013) Indicates the 64-bit version is garbage but the 32-bit version functions under wine v.1.9.14

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: In the mean time I'm flagging this as a possible duplicate of [Installing MS Office 2013 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS](http://askubuntu.com/questions/350167/installing-ms-office-2013-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts).

Comment: @DavidFoerster The recently released Wine 2.0 is supposed to support MS Office 2013, see https://itsfoss.com/wine-2-0-released/

Comment: @ByteCommander Nice find! Perhaps you can provide an answer as well?

Comment: I see no harm in trying the offline installer.

Comment: Close voters. Based on the info located by @ByteCommander I think this should remain open.

Comment: @ElderGeek Sorry, but unfortunately not. I have just coincidentally seen that article a few days ago, but personally I haven't done anything serious with Wine yet, at least not in the last year.

Comment: I think the question is clear. The newly released wine 2.0 is supposed to support MS Office 2013. And he is getting some problem. And question is not at all duplicate with the question asked about Ubuntu 12.04 as tagged by @DavidFoerster.

Comment: I have tried offline installer, the error says "Newer version is required".

Comment: @ElderGeek still it is a -bug-. This hould be reported to the wine developers. We are not going to be able to offer an answer. Oh and this error is also in the installer for office 2013 in wine 1.*: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26323&iTestingId=84530

Comment: @Apurba go into winecfg and set the windows version to windows 7 then it installs fine.

Comment: This Office 2013 error "Newer version required" does not appear to be uncommon [even under Windows](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_install-mso_other/office-needs-a-newer-version-of-windows/d97029ca-28b0-41e9-89ee-9403e47a3db0). Another related [post here.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/674623/problem-with-wine-you-need-a-version-of-latest-windows)

Comment: to avoid  "Newer version required": use Playonlinux, create new virtual drive, add wine 2.0 to it, use that, and configure it for win7: but after installation starts i get "error during setup"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wine 2.0 says it supports Office 2013. How do I actually install it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/879304/wine-2-0-says-it-supports-office-2013-how-do-i-actually-install-it)

Comment: In http://askubuntu.com/questions/879304/wine-2-0-says-it-supports-office-2013-how-do-i-actually-install-it you can see the answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/882084/24155

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug on DirectX. See i.e. [this testing on winehq](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26323&iTestingId=97543&bShowAll=true). Since `Wine 3.0` DirectX 11 can work around this. If you are on lower wine versions, a simple solution is to add a registry entry:

```
REGFILE=$(mktemp --tmpdir MaxVersionGLXXX.reg)
cat > "$REGFILE" <<_EOF_
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wine\Direct3D]
"MaxVersionGL"=dword:00030002
_EOF_

wine regedit "$REGFILE"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go to playonlinux select the app and then go to configure - and set wine version - 2.0 staging.

If you do not have 2.0 staging installed - use wine to install it first