# What is the most recent MSOffice that can be run under Wine/Playonlinux?

Tags: wine, playonlinux, microsoft-office

I use msoffice 2013 in Windows, but I was not able to install it in Wine or Playonlinux, where instead I use msoffice 2007.

I wander if some user can confirm the most recent MSOffice that run under Wine/Playonlinux.

I am not asking how to install 2013 (although finding how to do that would be great) - but what is the **latest** that clearly works.

---

MSOffice version history at the date of this question:

[image]

---

After comments keep asking to let go MSO:

*I am processing (translating) large documents that have been elaborated in new versions of MSo (eg 2013), and sometimes even mso-2007 isn't able to treat them properly, not to speak of LO, and I have to use latest versions of the program. - All the formatting has to remain completely unchanged when the sender re-opens his document that I return  translated  back to him (after I modify the text and save the document). -- But my work experience is much better in Linux than in Windows (desktop, internet browsing, other secondary tools that I need and have set up in Linux)  and that is why I am asking the question.*

Comment: Check on WineHQ - https://appdb.winehq.org/ . If you want to run msoffice I suggest you run windows. If you want to run Linux I suggest you use libreoffice. msoffice on wine will be most difficult and most prone to bugs / problems.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen The WineHQ AppDB does not seem to contain any reviews for Office 2013 on the new Wine 2.0 version yet, which claims to support them.

Comment: I know, but I find with wine there is a major difference between terms such as "supports" and the expectation of end users that a program works, out of the box, bug free, with little or no end user configuration. WineHQ is the best single source of information as well as any known bugs or configuration problems and thus a good reference.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen - I want to know which is the latest msoffice that *runs* (that is *tested* by some user) in Wine/Playonlinux (sorry for self-quoting, but still: `I use msoffice 2013 in Windows`), not merely (theoretically) "supported". -

Comment: [Can't run Office 2013 using Wine 2.0](http://askubuntu.com/q/875991/47206)

Comment: At least you can run office 2010 in play on linux. Though wine 2.0 is suppose to support office 2013, I am not able to make it work. But office 2010 works great with PlayOnLinux.

Comment: @Apurba - at a first try my playonlinux would quit with error after selecting msofice 2010 in its Office list. Trying in a separate system (I have different linuxes in multi-boot) it worked as expected. Should I post that as an answer or would  you prefer to do it?

Comment: Or forget ms office and use WPS office. It's the best linux office similar to MS office by far.

Comment: @PavlosTheodorou - have you tested it in advanced editing? I am processing (translating) large documents that have been elaborated in MSo 2013, and sometimes even mso-2007 isn't able to treat them properly, not to speak of LO, and I have to use latest versions of the program. But my work experience is much better in Linux and that is why I am asking the question. - All the formatting has to remain completely unchanged when the sender re-opens its document that I return  translated  back to him (after I modify the text and save the document) - Could WPS do better?

Comment: @PavlosTheodorou - testing that: just by opening and saving a document that used TimesNewRoman  WPS displays it and then saves it with a different font that looks very similar called Tinos.  --- So, that is a big problem that I found in the first ten seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Office 2016, 16.0 - NO.

---

### Office 2013, 15.0 - YES.

Answers  under [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/879304/47206) question seem to work.
I have installed it according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1007243/47206) answer, which was the most recent and is the most simple, as it only involves running a script in Playonlinux.

- **Word** seem to work decently, as well as **Excel**. **Outlook** starts (I never use it).
- **Powerpoint** has some bugs; from what I have seen, upon each startup one has to wait for a configuration progress to end and then select 'No' when asked to reboot Wine.
- **OneNote** doesn't work.
- Minimized windows are not seen in the task manager, panel or dock, but appear on the desktop as buttons/launchers which show window options when clicked. This may vary depending on the desktop environment, I have only tested in Plasma and Lxqt.

[image]

They are a bit annoying as  they stay on top of the normal Linux windows. This can be changed by altering the Wine configuration in POL to  allow the (Linux) window manager to control the windows.

[image]

In this way  the windows will then be accessible from task manager/panel as any other window, but [this bug](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=44552) would stop you from resizing, moving or otherwise changing the windows' state once you have put them into the "un-maximized" state. So, **avoid the un-maximize button**.

[image]

-- and just use the minimize option or leave the windows maximized and switch them with Alt-Tab or from the panel or dock.

(I do not recommend enabling the other option of running the windows in a virtual desktop: minimized windows would in this case become totally inaccessible.)

### UPDATE FOR 2013:

The above answer worked for me in 18.04, but not in 18.10. Instead I followed a combination of the other two answers there, that I have posted [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/a/1085219/47206).

---

### *Office 2010, 14.0 - YES*

Before installation be sure you have `winbind` installed:

```
sudo apt install winbind
```

- In Playonlinux 4.2.10 it is listed under ' Install - Office'

[image]

---

### *Office 2007 - YES*

More [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/155809/47206).

Comment: I installed the Office 2010 just a minutes ago. It works very good(just tried Powerpoint and Excel) but have some bugs(Powerpoint cant save in video and cant reproduce sounds.) But you can have some use of the program anyways. Tested on Lubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 5):

Since the new **Wine 2.0** version got released, you can now theoretically run **MS Office 2013** with it, according to the announcement on the official WineHQ website:

> The Wine team is proud to announce that the stable release Wine 2.0
>   is now available.
>
> This release represents over a year of development effort and around
>   6,600 individual changes. The main highlights are the support for
>   Microsoft Office 2013, and the 64-bit support on macOS.

The new Wine is not yet provided through the official Ubuntu repos as far as I know though, so you have to install it from their official Wine PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install winehq-devel
```

More information about installing Wine 2.0 on Ubuntu may also be found [here](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu).

After that, you should be able to install MS Office 2013 on Wine.

Sources:

- [OMG Ubuntu: "Wine 2.0 Released, Lets You Run Microsoft Office 2013 on Linux"](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/01/wine-2-0-released-supports-microsoft-office-2013)
- [WineHQ: Wine 2.0 Announcement](https://www.winehq.org/announce/2.0)

Comment: There is no debugging in that link and there are comments that it does not work. Have you tried this personally ? It also appears this is a pre-release version of wine 2.0? Just curious.

Comment: No, I am not currently using Wine personally and I don't own a license for Office 2013, so I could not verify the article. However, 2.0 got released as stable by the Wine devs and is also officially announced on their website, with one of the main improvements listed being support for MS Office 2013. Adding that link to my answer...

Comment: FWIW wineHQ has detailed instructions on installing wine 2.0 on Ubuntu - https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu . Same repos you listed, but some additional information that may be helpful.

Comment: Hmm... I'm going to install it and use the one week trial and see if it actually works...

Comment: @AndroidDev - It would be nice to know if it works and/or if additional configuration or modification of wine is required. May need additional steps for 64 bit , I am not sure.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I have a lot of scepticism that it is actually going to be usable. I have a hunch that it's going to be extremely slow.

Comment: Can anyone who is upvoting this answer confirm that it works and that no additional wine configuration is necessary ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen it does; I saw several topics in the web where people have it working. 1 thing I see as a must do: you have to set wine up to act as windows 7.

Comment: @Rinzwind - `I saw several topics in the web` = link please!

Comment: with playonlinux , added 2.0 staging, set wine to win7, tried to install msofice2013 x32 - got "error during setup".

Comment: can you confirm this works?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/879304/47206. The answer involving POL script (https://askubuntu.com/a/1007243/47206) worked fine for me in Ubuntu 18.04 Plasma /LXQT.

Answer (score 1):

Office 2016 (Word/Excel/Powerpoint) can run with POL and Wine 3.14 (latest 3.19 or 3.0 /3.4 did not work for me) on Ubuntu 18.04 with steps 1-5 [post Kevin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975104/how-do-i-install-ms-office-2016-on-playonlinux/1077935#1077935).
If you download the complete office 2016 IMG file, the installation includes your personal license and is already activated on start.

Comment: It didn't work for me in 18.10. Step 4 is to be done after the installation of msoffice I imagine, otherwise that file to be moved is absent. But executing msoffice setup.exe fails.