# How can I prepare Icon for run?

Tags: wine, playonlinux

I installed office using playonlinux and got icons like Microsoft Word 2010.desktop but I need to convert this Icon to able for launching or running the Word as the Microsoft Word 2010.desktop contains

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Microsoft Word 2010
Comment=PlayOnLinux
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/share/playonlinux/playonlinux --run "Microsoft Word 2010" %F
Icon=/home/user/.PlayOnLinux//icones/full_size/Microsoft Word 2010
Name[fr_FR]=Microsoft Word 2010
StartupWMClass=WINWORD.EXE
Categories=
```

Comment: Your Exec= line may be at fault. see (https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/desktop-entry-spec
) and [this](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s07.html)

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/878738/what-is-the-most-recent-msoffice-that-can-be-run-under-wine-playonlinux?rq=1