# Wine 2.0 says it supports Office 2013. How do I actually install it?

Tags: wine, microsoft-office

I managed to get Office 2013 almost to work with Crossover, but not with Wine 2.0. [Latest Wine is supposed to support Office 2013](https://www.winehq.org/announce/2.0), but I find no tutorials how to actually achieve that. So if the statement about support is true, how do I accomplish installing MS Office 2013 to Ubuntu with Wine 2.0?

Comment: Dupe if it ever gets answered: http://askubuntu.com/questions/875991/cant-run-office-2013-using-wine-2-0

Comment: I would have asked this on the Wine forums. It is their claim...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I installed Office 2013 and I used to get a black window after starting it up.
I fixed the black screen by following the solution posted in the [WineHQ-Forum](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=28446&p=109296&hilit=office%202013#p109284).

Here's what I did:

### Install Wine and Components

First, install wine 2.1 (or newer)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel
```

Install 'winbind'

```
sudo apt install winbind
```

### Create Clean 32bit Prefix for Win7

Crete a clean 32 bit prefix and start up winecfg:

```
WINEPREFIX=~/.wine/Office2013 WINEARCH=win32 winecfg
```

In the winecfg applications tab select "**Windows version: Windows 7**"
Close wine config and install winetricks

### Install Libraries

```
sudo apt install winetricks
```

Then start winetricks for your prefix

```
WINEPREFIX=~/.wine/Office2013 WINEARCH=win32 winetricks
```

accept "**select the default wineprefix**" with OK.
Now, select "**Install Windows DLL components**" and go and install **msxml6**

I also installed the cambria font, but that shouldn't matter.

Don't close winetricks just yet, you most likely want to fix the black screen bug.

#### Fix Black Window (optional)

In order to fix the black window that impedes Office 13 to be used, add the  `HKCU\Software\Wine\Direct3D\MaxVersionGL` new `DWORD` value `30002` (hexa) to the registry.

Here's how to do this:
In Winetricks select **Run regedit** and wait for the *Registry Editor* window to open.
In the folder tree expand HKEY_CURRENT_USER - Software - Wine and create a new key in the Wine folder. To do so, right click, select *new-->key* and name it **Direct3D**. Now create *new-->DWORD Value*, rename the file to **MaxVersionGL** and set the value data to **30002** (hexadecimal).
Close the Registry Editor window.

It should look like this:
[image: Registry Editor Entries]
Close the Registry Editor window.

Close the winetricks window and run installer:

### Install Office 2013

```
WINEPREFIX=~/.wine/Office2013 WINEARCH=win32 wine ~/PathTo/Office2013Setup.x86.exe
```

From here, the install runs and completes 100%.

Open one of the Office programs of your choice. They mostly work, but I found that the Word Math Typesetting does not work and Power Point may not start as well due to "not enough memory or system resources". So, still room for improvement.

Comment: Setup downloaded from Microsoft installs fine but ends up with black screen. Setup image downloaded via Heidoc fails to finalize installation and activation, even with config.xml.

Comment: I have followed the instruction, but I am still getting the black screen. Is there anything else that I can try?

Comment: Could you point where did you find all this info?

Comment: With ubuntu 16.04 and stock or updated winetricks, the  step "Install Libraries" tells me `sha1sum mismatch!  Rename /home/*/.cache/winetricks/msxml6/msxml6_x86.msi and try again.` . How do I circumvent this?

Comment: I'm getting a `File not found` error for my setup file, any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: Fix for black screen doesn't work.

Comment: wine-2.0.2 (Ubuntu 2.0.2-2ubuntu1) works. Don't need to get wine-2.1

Comment: You are a life saver. Thank you.

Comment: worked fine with wine 4.0

Comment: looks like there's no wine ppa for Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: `WINEPREFIX=~/.wine/Office2013 WINEARCH=win32 winecfg` fails, complaining *`~/.wine/Office2013` is not an absolute path*. If you encounter such a problem, just replace `~` with `$HOME`.

Comment: Works with Wine 6 too

Answer (score 15):

In addition to Philippe's answer I installed the following from winetricks:

```
msftedit
riched20
riched30
riched32
vb6run
```

That solved the PowerPoint "not enough memory or system resources" issue and black fields issue

Comment: I tried wine 3.1 from devel install. winetricks had soem errors installing rich* DLLs. I used newest winetricks from source: https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks/blob/master/src/winetricks
So I could install all DLLs and it worked.

Comment: It's `richtx32` (not `riched32`), but it works for me :)

Answer (score 6):

### Install Office 2013 pro 32bit

This solution is tested on Ubuntu 17.10 with wine 2.0.2.

### Required Dependencies

We need a clean 32bit wine prefix and some packages.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
sudo apt install cabextract fonts-liberation winbind wine wine32 wine-gecko2.21
```

> - 32bit `wine` installation
> - `winbind` for some samba functions
> - `gecko`for internet content popups
> - `cabextract` and `wget` for downloading `corefonts` through winetricks
> - `fonts-liberation` for the free alternatives to Arial etc.

Note that I also recommend `wine-3.0` due to its DirectX11 Support. To install, use

```
wget https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key
sudo apt-key add Release.key
sudo apt-add-repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/'

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine-stable winehq-stable
```

### Installation Process

[The recipie](https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks/pull/939) is now upstream on [winetricks](https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks/). We need a clean 32bit prefix for it. If you do not have one, prepend `WINEPREFIX="${HOME}/.wine-office2013pro"` to the wine commands.

First get the newest winetricks:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks -O ~/Downloads/winetricks
chmod u+x ~/Downloads/winetricks
```

and then use the recipie on a 32bit wine prefix.

```
WINEARCH=win32 wine wineboot
~/Downloads/winetricks office2013pro
```

[image: msxml6 is installed due to an incompatibility of libxml.] [image: the setup is straight forward.]

### First start

The installed desktop files are located in

```
~/.local/share/applications/wine/Programs/Microsoft Office 2013
```

[image: welcome message] [image: powerpoint]

There should be a welcome messages that connects to the internet (only on wine-3.0) and lets you activate the product.

- *Microsoft Word 2013* will start fine. Although, there are certainly [some bugs in it](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=33708).
- *Microsoft PowerPoint 2013* has some unresolved issues like the [black slides](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42611). Sometimes it also refuses to start at first. If so, do not press reboot when asked, as it will exit wine.

[image: do not press reboot in powerpoint]

### Product Activaton

On `wine-3.0` activation is possible over the internet.

On `wine-2.0`the product can be activated via telephone. The phone number is found [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/-telephone-activation-is-no-longer-supported-for-your-product-error-when-activating-office-9b016cd2-0811-4cb3-b896-5a6a13177713). For us, it is 866-421-7141

Comment: +1... Based on this I was able to install and have a working setup (without using the refereed `winetricks office2013pro`). Created a 32-bit prefix. Then after `winetricks corefonts tahoma riched20 msxml6` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wine\Direct3D` trick, installed using own medium. Even updated to SP1 and installed additional language packs. Everything I've used working properly so far...

Comment: @Kanchu - very helpful to me, who thought that the black screen problem will not appear during this solution. In order to put it all together, I have summed up all steps in this answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1085219/47206

Comment: @Kanchu look at [the verb](https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks/blob/master/src/winetricks#L13157-L13226) and you will see that winetricks does all the magic for you.

Answer (score 2):

**Okay friends! Here's my answer!**

This question was originally asked in 2017-02-03. In 2018-02-17 we already have newer versions of wine.

I posted this answer because I believe it is a solution **accessible to more people**.

Below is a script for use with PlayOnLinux ( https://www.playonlinux.com/en/ ). It was based on a script created originally by **Quentin Pâris** (thanks guy! =D ).

To do the installation we need the following resources: **wine**, **winetricks**, **winbind** and **playonlinux**.

**NOTE:** winetricks and winbind are usually installed along with wine. To test if they are present use the commands `winetricks -V` and `wbinfo -V` respectively!

With contributions from @Naheel and @Philippe .

---

**TO USE THE SCRIPT:**

Save the script below to a text file (eg: `office2013.bash`).

Start PlayOnLinux, open the script file above...

[image: Open the script file.]

... , run it...

[image: Run script file.]

... and follow the on-screen instructions.

---

**PLAYONLINUX SCRIPT:**

```
#!/bin/bash

# CHANGELOG
# [Quentin Pâris and Eduardo Lucio (Questor)] (2018-02-17 15-24)
# Version 1.1.0.0
# Paris/Brazil

# >>>>>>>>>>
# Under BSD License!

# Copyright (c) 2018, Quentin Pâris and Eduardo Lucio
# All rights reserved.

# Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
# modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
#     * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
#       notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
#     * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
#       notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
#       documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
#     * Neither the name of the free software community nor the
#       names of its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products
#       derived from this software without specific prior written permission.

# THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND
# ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED
# WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
# DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL Quentin Pâris and Eduardo Lucio BE LIABLE FOR ANY
# DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES
# (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES;
# LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND
# ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
# (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
# SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

# <<<<<<<<<<

# NOTE: Complete liste of references! By Questor
# https://github.com/PlayOnLinux/POL-POM-4/blob/master/lib/wine.lib
# https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-2665-Microsoft_Office_2013.html
# http://wiki.playonlinux.com/index.php/Scripting_-_Chapter_11:_List_of_Functions
# http://wiki.playonlinux.com/index.php/Components_and_Functions
# https://www.playonlinux.com/repository/source.php?script=822
# https://github.com/PlayOnLinux/POL-POM-4/blob/367e50865168b5b931611fa33b0c1d8426143a90/lib/scripts.lib
# https://github.com/PlayOnLinux/POL-POM-4/blob/367e50865168b5b931611fa33b0c1d8426143a90/lib/wine.lib
# https://askubuntu.com/questions/879304/wine-2-0-says-it-supports-office-2013-how-do-i-actually-install-it
# https://github.com/RobertJames/playonlinux/blob/75ef37523f299255a539a89b63dc87d7afc096d4/template.POL

# >>>>>>>>>>
# Initialization!

[ "$PLAYONLINUX" = "" ] && exit 0
source "$PLAYONLINUX/lib/sources"

PREFIX="office2013"

WINEVERSION="3.0"

TITLE="Microsoft Office 2013"

# NOTE: Images to use! By Questor
POL_GetSetupImages "https://i.imgur.com/licFVuF.png" "https://i.imgur.com/ff6PkEZ.png" "$TITLE"

POL_SetupWindow_Init
POL_SetupWindow_SetID 2665

POL_SetupWindow_presentation "$TITLE" "Microsoft" "http://www.microsoft.com" "Quentin Pâris and Eduardo Lucio" "$PREFIX"

POL_Debug_Init

# <<<<<<<<<<

# >>>>>>>>>>
# Perform some validations!

POL_RequiredVersion 4.2.12 || POL_Debug_Fatal "$TITLE won't work with $APPLICATION_TITLE $VERSION!\nPlease update!"

if [ "$POL_OS" = "Linux" ]; then
    wbinfo -V || POL_Debug_Fatal "Please install winbind before installing $TITLE!"
fi

if [ "$POL_OS" = "Mac" ]; then

    # NOTE: Samba support! By Quentin Pâris
    POL_Call POL_GetTool_samba3
    source "$POL_USER_ROOT/tools/samba3/init"

fi

POL_Wine_WaitBefore "$TITLE"
[ "$CDROM" ] && cd "$CDROM"

if [ ! "$(file $SetupIs | grep 'x86-64')" = "" ]; then
    POL_Debug_Fatal "$(eval_gettext "The 64bits version is not compatible! Sorry!")";
fi

# NOTE: Check if "winetricks" is present! By Questor
winetricks -V || POL_Debug_Fatal "Please install winetricks before installing $TITLE!"

POL_System_SetArch "x86"
POL_SetupWindow_InstallMethod "LOCAL,DVD"

if [ "$INSTALL_METHOD" = "DVD" ]; then
    POL_SetupWindow_cdrom
    POL_SetupWindow_check_cdrom "x86/setup.exe" "setup.exe"
    SetupIs="$CDROM_SETUP"
    cd "$CDROM"
else
    POL_SetupWindow_browse "$(eval_gettext 'Please select the setup file to run!')" "$TITLE"
    SetupIs="$APP_ANSWER"
fi

# <<<<<<<<<<

# >>>>>>>>>>
# Prepare resources for installation!

# NOTE: Install wine version if isn't available. This is necessary because 
# even though "POL_Wine_PrefixCreate" solves this, we end up having 
# problems when the required version is not available and it tries to 
# install it! Questor
# [Ref.: https://github.com/PlayOnLinux/POL-POM-4/blob/master/lib/wine.lib]
POL_Wine_InstallVersion "$WINEVERSION"

POL_Wine_SelectPrefix "$PREFIX"
POL_Wine_PrefixCreate "$WINEVERSION"

Set_OS "win7"

# <<<<<<<<<<

# >>>>>>>>>>
# Install!

# NOTE: Installs office! By Questor
POL_Wine "$SetupIs"
POL_Wine_WaitExit "$TITLE"

# <<<<<<<<<<

# >>>>>>>>>>
# Prepare resources for applications!

# NOTE: Uses native special version of "riched20" installed by Office 2013! 
# Fix the "black fields" issue! By Questor
# [Ref.: http://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=23126&p=95555#p95555]
POL_Wine_OverrideDLL "native,builtin" "riched20"

# NOTE: Fix "move and change the window size (maximize/minimize/restore/resize 
# etc...) bugs"! By Questor
# [Ref.: https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=44552]
Set_Managed "Off"

# <<<<<<<<<<

# >>>>>>>>>>
# Create shortcuts, entries to extensions and finalize!

# NOTE: Create shortcuts! By Questor
POL_Shortcut "WINWORD.EXE" "Microsoft Word 2013" "" "" "Office;WordProcessor;"
POL_Shortcut "EXCEL.EXE" "Microsoft Excel 2013" "" "" "Office;Spreadsheet;"
POL_Shortcut "POWERPNT.EXE" "Microsoft Powerpoint 2013" "" "" "Office;Presentation;"

# NOTE: No category for collaborative work? By Quentin Pâris
POL_Shortcut "ONENOTE.EXE" "Microsoft OneNote 2013" "" "" "Network;InstantMessaging;"

# NOTE: "Calendar;ContactManagement;"? By Quentin Pâris
POL_Shortcut "OUTLOOK.EXE" "Microsoft Outlook 2013" "" "" "Network;Email;"

# NOTE: Add an entry to PlayOnLinux's extension file. If the entry already 
# exists, it will replace it! By Questor
# [Ref.: https://github.com/PlayOnLinux/POL-POM-4/blob/master/lib/playonlinux.lib]
POL_Extension_Write doc "Microsoft Word 2013"
POL_Extension_Write docx "Microsoft Word 2013"
POL_Extension_Write xls "Microsoft Excel 2013"
POL_Extension_Write xlsx "Microsoft Excel 2013"
POL_Extension_Write ppt "Microsoft Powerpoint 2013"
POL_Extension_Write pptx "Microsoft Powerpoint 2013"

if [ "$POL_OS" = "Mac" ]; then
    POL_Shortcut_InsertBeforeWine "Microsoft Word 2013" "source \"$POL_USER_ROOT/tools/samba3/init\""
    POL_Shortcut_InsertBeforeWine "Microsoft Excel 2013" "source \"$POL_USER_ROOT/tools/samba3/init\""
    POL_Shortcut_InsertBeforeWine "Microsoft Powerpoint 2013" "source \"$POL_USER_ROOT/tools/samba3/init\""
    POL_Shortcut_InsertBeforeWine "Microsoft OneNote 2013" "source \"$POL_USER_ROOT/tools/samba3/init\""
    POL_Shortcut_InsertBeforeWine "Microsoft Outlook 2013" "source \"$POL_USER_ROOT/tools/samba3/init\""
fi

POL_SetupWindow_message "$(eval_gettext '$TITLE has been installed successfully!\n\nThanks!\nBy Quentin Pâris and Eduardo Lucio')" "$TITLE"
POL_SetupWindow_Close

# <<<<<<<<<<

exit 0
```

---

**FURTHER INFORMATION ABOUT THIS SCRIPT:** https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-2665.html

Comment: You are installing `msxml6 msftedit riched30 vb6run`. Can comment on why? On the winhq site there is a lot of discussion about those packages but I can not reproduce why they are needed. [I am putting together some refs](https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks/pull/939) to bring clarity to the installation procedure. On my end, only really needed was `riched20`. 

I can not understand the edits by Questor for setting Wine-Version to 3.2 during installation and to 2.22 afterwards. For me, installation went fine on wine-2.0. and wine-3.0.

Comment: ok. so i checked the bugreports on winhq. You only need msxml6 in some wine versions prior to a bugfix in libxml2.

Comment: @ukos About "I can not understand the edits by Questor for setting Wine to Version 3.2 during installation and to 2.22 afterwards", this was done because wine version "2.22" fails with the installer and version "3.2" fails with Office applications. This is what happens on my environment (Linux Manjaro). What specific version did you use of "wine" "3"? Thanks!

Comment: @ukos "You only need msxml6 in some wine versions prior to a bugfix in libxml2" -> Which wine version specifically? Tell me the wine version so I can do the tests.

Comment: plain `wine-3.0` seems to work for installation and for run of the actual application. Could you report back to [winehq](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=33708) if this is a known bug?

Comment: regarding msxml: it is [bug 43581](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=43581).

Comment: EXTRA: Information about related bug in Office 2013 -> https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=44552 (Office 2013 - Move and change the window size (maximize/minimize/restore/resize etc...) bugs)

Comment: "You are installing msxml6 msftedit riched30 vb6run" -> "fix the PowerPoint \"not enough memory or system resources\" issue and black fields issue" (https://askubuntu.com/a/964712/134723) @Naheel

Comment: There is actually no fix yet [for the black flelds issue on winehq](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42611) and the cited post is not changing anything for me. I rather think it is based on hearsay and should not get adopted because it misses profound analysis.

Comment: @ukos For some reason the process I use to install Office 2013 no longer works. Now even making the change in the registry the "black screen" failure continues. =[

Comment: in wine-3.0 the regex is not needed anymore. If not try applying the regex again https://askubuntu.com/questions/875991/black-screen-issue-in-office-2013-using-wine-2-0/889372

Comment: @ukos See the "EXTRA! - Install using pure bash (system wine):" section in this thread for more details about the installation process I am using now. Thanks!

Comment: @ukos "in wine-3.0 the regex is not needed anymore" -> I did what you said, but the problem persists =[ . The wine version I am using is "3.1".

Comment: Take a look at this [PR](https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks/pull/939). It has a silent/unattended install option to make a clean and simple install. There are still some issues. Maybe move the discussion there.

Comment: @ukos I created a thread about the current problem ("process I use to install Office 2013 no longer works") https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008411/wine-3-1-office-2013-starts-with-a-black-screen Thanks!

Comment: @ukos Wine -> "wine 3.0". Packages -> "none". Fix the "black fields" issue (not for PowerPoint) -> "\"native,builtin\" \"riched20\"". Thanks!

Comment: PowerPoint 2013 has the following bug: "most slides in the Slide pane and New Slide dropdown appear as black boxes, but sometimes they appear as white boxes with a red cross (in the New Slide dropdown) or appear normally." -> https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42611 @ukos

Comment: That is an unresolved bug (Pretty annoying, too)

Comment: Worked fine in 18.04 just by running the script in POL.

Comment: To have the different windows in the panel task manager or dock: alter the Wine configuration in POL to allow the (Linux) window manager to control the windows, then avoid [this bug](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=44552) by never using the un-maximize button. More here: https://askubuntu.com/a/880376/47206

Answer (score 0):

Using PlayOnLinux is more simpler, just follow this video :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6HhKWXdCWBM.
In video description you'll find :

1. - Download PlayOnLinux
2. - Install winbind
3. - Setup PlayOnLinux
4. - Install Wine 3.1 and 2.20-staging
5. - Create virtual drive Office2013
6. - Copy script from `https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/3ukrfh/microsoft_office_2013_on_linux_using_playonlinux/`
7. - Modify only one input
8. - Paste script in PlayOnLinux
9. - Setup default Office 2013 install manager
10. - Setup takes abaout 5-10 mins
11. - Setup 2.20-staging version of Wine
12. - Go!
13. - Microsoft Outlook 2013 ! - fail. Microsoft OneNote 2013 too