# Wine 3.1 - Office 2013 starts with a black screen!

Tags: wine, winetricks

Office 2013 starts with a black screen!

[image]

**Installation scheme used:**

```
WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/office2013 wine wineboot
WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/office2013 wine '<PATH_TO_SETUP_EXE>/setup.exe'
WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/office2013 wine 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\WINWORD.EXE'
```

**These interventions did not work:**

```
cat << EOF > "Direct3D.reg"
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wine\Direct3D]
"MaxVersionGL"=dword:00030002


EOF
WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/office2013 wine regedit "Direct3D.reg"
rm -f "Direct3D.reg"

WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/office2013 winetricks -q corefonts
WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/office2013 winetricks -q msxml6
WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/office2013 winetricks -q riched20
```

**NOTE I:** "wbind" installed.
**NOTE II:** 3.1 is the wine version.

**The output from the terminal (final part):**

```
[...]
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0034:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetViewports Multiple viewports not implemented.
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetScissorRects Multiple scissor rects not implemented.
0035:fixme:d2d:d2d_factory_CreateDevice iface 0x11a63220, dxgi_device 0x75411e8, device 0x7b6fb7c stub!
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetViewports Multiple viewports not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetScissorRects Multiple scissor rects not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0034:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetViewports Multiple viewports not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetScissorRects Multiple scissor rects not implemented.
0035:fixme:d2d:d2d_factory_CreateDevice iface 0x11a631f8, dxgi_device 0x75411e8, device 0x7b6fb7c stub!
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetViewports Multiple viewports not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetScissorRects Multiple scissor rects not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0034:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetViewports Multiple viewports not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetScissorRects Multiple scissor rects not implemented.
0035:fixme:d2d:d2d_factory_CreateDevice iface 0x11a63270, dxgi_device 0x75411e8, device 0x7b6fb7c stub!
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetViewports Multiple viewports not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetScissorRects Multiple scissor rects not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0034:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetViewports Multiple viewports not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetScissorRects Multiple scissor rects not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0035:fixme:d2d:d2d_factory_CreateDevice iface 0x11a62ee0, dxgi_device 0x75411e8, device 0x7b6fb7c stub!
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetViewports Multiple viewports not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetScissorRects Multiple scissor rects not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetViewports Multiple viewports not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetScissorRects Multiple scissor rects not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0034:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetViewports Multiple viewports not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetScissorRects Multiple scissor rects not implemented.
0035:fixme:d2d:d2d_factory_CreateDevice iface 0x11a64f08, dxgi_device 0x75411e8, device 0x7b6fb7c stub!
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetViewports Multiple viewports not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetScissorRects Multiple scissor rects not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetViewports Multiple viewports not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetScissorRects Multiple scissor rects not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetViewports Multiple viewports not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetScissorRects Multiple scissor rects not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0034:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetViewports Multiple viewports not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetScissorRects Multiple scissor rects not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0035:fixme:d2d:d2d_factory_CreateDevice iface 0x11b953c0, dxgi_device 0x75411e8, device 0x7b6fb7c stub!
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetViewports Multiple viewports not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetScissorRects Multiple scissor rects not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetViewports Multiple viewports not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetScissorRects Multiple scissor rects not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0034:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetViewports Multiple viewports not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetScissorRects Multiple scissor rects not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0035:fixme:d2d:d2d_factory_CreateDevice iface 0x11b91678, dxgi_device 0x75411e8, device 0x7b6fb7c stub!
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetViewports Multiple viewports not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetScissorRects Multiple scissor rects not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetViewports Multiple viewports not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetScissorRects Multiple scissor rects not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetViewports Multiple viewports not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetScissorRects Multiple scissor rects not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0034:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetViewports Multiple viewports not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetScissorRects Multiple scissor rects not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0035:fixme:d2d:d2d_factory_CreateDevice iface 0x11a64f68, dxgi_device 0x75411e8, device 0x7b6fb7c stub!
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetViewports Multiple viewports not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetScissorRects Multiple scissor rects not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetViewports Multiple viewports not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetScissorRects Multiple scissor rects not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetViewports Multiple viewports not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetScissorRects Multiple scissor rects not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetViewports Multiple viewports not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetScissorRects Multiple scissor rects not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0034:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetViewports Multiple viewports not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetScissorRects Multiple scissor rects not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0035:fixme:d2d:d2d_factory_CreateDevice iface 0x11b95760, dxgi_device 0x75411e8, device 0x7b6fb7c stub!
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetViewports Multiple viewports not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetScissorRects Multiple scissor rects not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetViewports Multiple viewports not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetScissorRects Multiple scissor rects not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0034:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetViewports Multiple viewports not implemented.
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetScissorRects Multiple scissor rects not implemented.
0035:fixme:d2d:d2d_factory_CreateDevice iface 0x11b92bc0, dxgi_device 0x75411e8, device 0x7b6fb7c stub!
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d:wined3d_buffer_create Ignoring access flags (pool).
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetViewports Multiple viewports not implemented.
0009:fixme:d3d11:d3d10_device_RSSetScissorRects Multiple scissor rects not implemented.
0034:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0034:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:d2d:d2d_factory_CreateDevice iface 0x11b30408, dxgi_device 0x75411e8, device 0x7b6fb7c stub!
0035:fixme:d2d:d2d_factory_CreateDevice iface 0x11b30408, dxgi_device 0x75411e8, device 0x7b6fb7c stub!
0034:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:d2d:d2d_factory_CreateDevice iface 0x116b6360, dxgi_device 0x75411e8, device 0x7b6fb7c stub!
0035:fixme:dxgi:dxgi_device_GetMaximumFrameLatency iface 0x75411e8, max_latency 0x11b2a74c stub!
0035:fixme:dxgi:dxgi_device_SetMaximumFrameLatency iface 0x75411e8, max_latency 3 stub!
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0009:fixme:win:IsWindowRedirectedForPrint (0x100aa): stub
0009:fixme:win:IsWindowRedirectedForPrint (0x100a8): stub
0009:fixme:win:IsWindowRedirectedForPrint (0x800c4): stub
0009:fixme:win:IsWindowRedirectedForPrint (0x200c6): stub
0009:fixme:win:IsWindowRedirectedForPrint (0x100b6): stub
0009:fixme:win:IsWindowRedirectedForPrint (0x20088): stub
0034:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:d2d:d2d_factory_CreateDevice iface 0x11b2dc90, dxgi_device 0x75411e8, device 0x7b6fb7c stub!
0035:fixme:d2d:d2d_factory_CreateDevice iface 0x11b2dc90, dxgi_device 0x75411e8, device 0x7b6fb7c stub!
0034:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:d2d:d2d_factory_CreateDevice iface 0x11b25fc8, dxgi_device 0x75411e8, device 0x7b6fb7c stub!
0035:fixme:d2d:d2d_factory_CreateDevice iface 0x11b25fc8, dxgi_device 0x75411e8, device 0x7b6fb7c stub!
0035:fixme:dxgi:dxgi_device_GetMaximumFrameLatency iface 0x75411e8, max_latency 0x11b33c64 stub!
0035:fixme:dxgi:dxgi_device_SetMaximumFrameLatency iface 0x75411e8, max_latency 3 stub!
0034:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0034:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:d2d:d2d_factory_CreateDevice iface 0x116a35d0, dxgi_device 0x75411e8, device 0x7b6fb7c stub!
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0034:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0034:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0034:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0034:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0034:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0034:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
0035:fixme:advapi:EventProviderEnabled deadbeef, 4, 2: stub
003f:fixme:ntdll:EtwUnregisterTraceGuids deadbeef: stub
003f:fixme:ntdll:EtwUnregisterTraceGuids deadbeef: stub
```

Comment: which program exactly did you start for getting this log.
other than that, I doubt you will get bugfixes on askubuntu. Better go to winehq with that.

Comment: @ukos "which program exactly did you start" -> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\WINWORD.EXE".

Comment: "Better go to winehq with that."- > I'll do that! Thanks!

Comment: besides that, you get a lot of d3d errors. If you are on wine3 why do you even apply the regex workaround for d3d? wine3 has native support for directx 10 and 11. Try to keep your wineprefixes as clean as possible.

Comment: @ukos "Better go to winehq with that."- > https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=44574

Comment: "regex workaround for d3d" -> I'm not using it anymore. Thanks

Comment: then update your post.

Comment: Please, see "These interventions did not work" section on this thread.

Comment: I'm using the process inside "Installation scheme used" section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason when I changed the version of wine (see image) in PlayOnLinux the Office 2013 stopped working even though I reinstall it in the same version that was working earlier. I think this may be a bug in Wine or PlayOnLinux. The solution was remove the wine, wine-mono, wine_gecko, winetricks, and playonlinux, restart the OS and reinstall everything again.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In PlayOnLinux, after installing office 2013 with wine 3.1, I reverted back the wine version to 2.20-staging (you will have a warning, just say yes).

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6HhKWXdCWBM

Answer (score 0):

**PREREQUISITES**

Ubuntu 19.10 64Bits

1. Install Samba
   `sudo apt install winbind`
2. Install Last Wine Version --> tested with *Wine Staging 5.0-rc3*
   https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

---

**Install Office 2013 Pro 32bits**

1. Create the WINEPREFIX (32bits) (*64 bits doesn't work*)
   `WINEPREFIX=/media/data/10_Apps/MS_Office/WinePrefix/ WINEARCH=win32 winecfg`
2. Install *msxml6* with winetricks
   `WINEPREFIX=/media/data/10_Apps/MS_Office/WinePrefix/ WINEARCH=win32 winetricks msxml6`
3. Mount the ISO Office 2013 File and open a Terminal from the Folder
4. Install Office inside the created Prefix
   `WINEPREFIX=/media/data/10_Apps/MS_Office/WinePrefix/ WINEARCH=win32 wine setup.exe`

---

**Remove Black Boxes**

`WINEPREFIX=/media/data/10_Apps/MS_Office/WinePrefix/ WINEARCH=win32 winetricks riched20`