# Winetricks registry editor window is empty

Tags: wine

I have successfully installed MSOffice 2013 using [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1007046/47206) answer.

But I am facing the "black screen" problem, which I am trying to solve as indicated [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/882084/47206) - in an answer under the same question (an answer which provides another solution, which didn't work for me).

> In order to fix the black window that impedes Office 13 to be used,
>   add the HKCU\Software\Wine\Direct3D\MaxVersionGL new DWORD value 30002
>   (hexa) to the registry.

For that, the solution is to run `winetricks` and make those changes.

But given that msoffice is installed at `~/.wine32` the idea would be to run

```
WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32 WINEARCH=win32 winetricks
```

What I get is this:

```
~$ WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32 WINEARCH=win32 winetricks
Using winetricks 20180815 - sha256sum: 29e664ec1e879271a33167bf367deaa188cbe803d44b540e692bd669c44a2804 with wine-3.18 (Ubuntu 3.18-2) and WINEARCH=win32
winetricks GUI enabled, using zenity 3.30.0
```

It opens without warning

[image]

[image]

but then it's just an empty window

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalled and purged Wine, deleted ~/.wine folder.

Installed the stable version 3.0.

Followed the steps presented in my other answer [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/a/1085219/47206) in order to install MSOffice.

---

It seems that by some odd occurrence I had created the `~/.wine32` folder. I have noticed that afterwards, during the successful installation which was not affected by the  problem above, no such folder was created.

Also, at the time of the problem described in the question, the Wine version at system level was 3.18 (one that I had installed in Playonlinux for a parallel effort to install MSOffice in PoL, but it somehow became the system version too). Maybe that was a big part of the problem. Replacing it with 3.0 was probably the thing to do.

The black-screen problem can be fixed as expected, as seen in my linked answer, while the problem with regedit discussed here above doesn't occur when following those steps.