# MS Powerpoint 2016 installed using wine on Ubuntu 20.04 cannot start

Tags: 20.04, wine, playonlinux, microsoft-powerpoint

I have installed MS Office 2016 32 bit version on my Ubuntu 20.04 using wine. All the services work wonderfully, except powerpoint. It says on starting that it cannot be opened due lack of resources. I have installation through playonlinux but same issue.

Any help will be appreciated.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHzVN.jpg)

Comment: You may want to try PlayOnLinux - see https://askubuntu.com/q/975104/66509 .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wine 2.0 says it supports Office 2013. How do I actually install it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879304/wine-2-0-says-it-supports-office-2013-how-do-i-actually-install-it)