# PowerPoint from Office 2013 shows blank slides on startup

Tags: wine, playonlinux, microsoft-office

I just installed Office 2013 on Kubuntu following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3A4fzqj4SQ&t=432s) video (using PlayOnLinux and wine). The gif below shows what happens when I try to open PowerPoint. It starts all right but the slides are blank (just a gray background). No matter what I try to draw/write on the slide it just stays blank.

[image: PowerPoint Blank Slides]

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

EDIT: Might be useful to mention that Excel and Word work perfect.

Comment: I just tried drawing some random shape in the slide, even though I cannot see it, and then I exported the presentation to pdf. I could see the shapes in the output pdf, but still not in the PowerPoint. This is very strange...

Comment: WineHQ - Microsoft Office (installer only) 2013 (32 bit) https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26323  https://askubuntu.com/questions/879304/wine-2-0-says-it-supports-office-2013-how-do-i-actually-install-it

Comment: Check if [Office online snap](https://snapcraft.io/office365webdesktop) works for you. `sudo snap install office365webdesktop --beta`. Also give [Onlyoffice](https://askubuntu.com/a/1332488/124466) a try.