# Cannot find the HKCU\Software\Wine\Direct3D\MaxVersionGL for editing

Tags: wine, playonlinux, microsoft-office, winetricks

As is said on this Question ([Can't run Office 2013 using Wine 2.0](https://askubuntu.com/questions/875991/cant-run-office-2013-using-wine-2-0)) to solve the black screen issue in Office 2013 using wine, one needs to edit the HKCU\Software\Wine\Direct3D\MaxVersionGL value. I have searched wuth regedit and in the playonlinux reg.editor but i cannot find the Direct3D folder/files. Am i missing something?

Best Benjamin.

Answer (score 1):

Roseanne from the winehq just replied and give the missing idea: If it doesn't exist....create it! 
Here you will find the answer:
https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26323
Just add the new key with the value in regedit or in the regedit of playonlinux.